# titanium paypal module not working properly

Tags: paypal, appcelerator, titanium-modules

I have horrible experience with titanium paypal module (ti.paypal). After I click the "pay with PayPal" yellow button. A paypal form popup but screen size is too small and it scrawls. I want that popup to fill entire screen. In short how to set size for it. Please see below image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dDyu.jpg

My code

```
var payPal = require('paypal');
var button = payPal.addButtonToWindow(project);
$.paymentInfo.add(button);
```

Where project is an object with price , and order number. 
Please help me how to fill the size of paypal form that covers my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your issue is already on JIRA and watch it there to help us prioritise:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20MOD%20AND%20component%20%3D%20Paypal

If not, please create a JIRA ticket in the AC project.